# Approximation of functions by continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $g: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Define

$$h(t):= \begin{cases}1 \quad g(t) \geq 0 \\ -1 \quad g(t) < 0\end{cases}$$

Can we find a sequence $(h_n)_n$ of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$  with $-1 \leq h_n \leq 1$ such that $h_n \to h$ pointwise?

This is part of a proof I'm reading.

Comment: Is there any connection between $h_n$ and $h(t)$ ?

Comment: You have not mentioned $g(t)$, nor defined $(h_n)_n$.  There are large holes in the question

Comment: Thanks. Edited. I guess I really need some more sleep :P

Comment: @user745578 yes we can... to find a function just recall what happens for $$f_n: [0,1] \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto x^n$$ as $n \to \infty$ or alternatively take $$f_n:  \Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto (1-nx)\cdot 1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}$$

Comment: @Gono Can you maybe write an explicit answer with the explicit function that works?

Comment: @user745578 Both functions should give you a hint to solve this by your own… stackexchange is not a solution factory…

Comment: @Gono Apart from the fact that $g$ can have an infinite number of vanishing points and that $h(t)= 1$ on closed intervals... which make the technicalities far beyond the hint you provided.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thanks! I'm trying the hint but I can't manage to get it in the right shape.

Comment: Not sure if this is the type of answer you're looking for, but $\tanh(nx)$ should do as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I hope I have not messed up the calculations here.
Consider the following sequence of continuous functions
$$h_n(t) = \begin{cases}1 \ , \quad g(t) \geq \frac{1}{n} \\
                   2ng(t)-1 \ , \quad  0 \leq g(t) < \frac{1}{n}\\
                  -1 \ , \quad g(t) < 0\end{cases}  $$
Note that this function is indeed continuous (that is because $g$ is continuous) and $h_n\to h$ pointwise (since eventually -in other words for sufficiently large $n$- for every $t\in [-1,1]$, $g(t) \in \Bbb R \backslash [0, \frac{1}{n})$)

The idea is creating a little "space" on every discontinuouity so I can "connect" the two pieces and by getting the "space" smaller and smaller we get the convergence.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at it in detail!